# Why does printf crash bluetooth low energy on ti sensortag

Tags: android, c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been working on a Ti cc2650 SensorTag for the past week or so trying to add another service to the already existing services within the SensorTag example application. At first, I thought it was the code specific to the actual service I wrote that was breaking the BLE functionality; however, in deeper analysis of the problem I noticed this was actually due to the use of `printf`. 
I understand that `printf` is a little more resource heavy than say `Display_print0`, `System_printf` or even `puts` but even these "lighter" methods still seem to crash the app.

From what I understand about the situation I would assume that `printf` and the other display methods take too long to display to the console and use too much memory in the process. Something about this delay and allocation of memory causes a miss match in the BLE signal and thus results in a terminated connection between the SensorTag and my Android.

I am using Code Composer Studio, could this be an issue with the IDE I am using?

Is this an Android Problem?

Is this not something the SensorTag supports?

Using something do display text to the console is more of a means to an end for me rather than the end goal obviously. I rely (maybe too heavily) on text output to know when things do what but thoughts on this matter would be accepted and helpful to me.

**Note:** for what it's worth `printf` **does** display to the console it just breaks the BLE connection nearly every time.

Thanks

Comment: Can you increase the baud rate?

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/bluetooth/f/538/t/736364 is relating to this question. For baud rate changes I am not totally sure if that's possible. I can check that out and report back. It would be really awesome if I could connect through uart via a putty or something. I have laid out my setting in that link

Comment: You are probably retargeting printf through a USART.

Comment: mmm... possibly? I'm not sure.

Comment: @FiddlingBits would it be possible to route through UART? I'm like a super newb, if that's possible, ignorance is everywhere, do you know of any decent documentation on this device for this specific task? I don't even know if the jargon words I am using even make sense.

Comment: I found a CC2650F128.ccxml file that has a few settings pertaining to UART and baud rates

Comment: Sorry I can't help.  Good luck.